# Compact Framework DirectShow Based Camera with Preview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've an example (wimobot.org) of a working directshow camera (not based on CameraDialog), but this example doesn't includes preview. I don't know how to implement the direct show filter for the preview, any sample code in C# or Visual Basic .Net?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the reply to an old question, but I've been looking for this for a while myself and have just come accross a DirectShow .Net CF Wrapper here:

http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/directshownetcf/