# How to use USB web camera in .Net Compact Framework?

Tags: .net

How to use USB web camera in .Net Compact Framework (on Windows CE based OS)?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, there is a similar question here [Compact Framework DirectShow Based Camera with Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149363/compact-framework-directshow-based-camera-with-preview)

One answer there recommends using this component: http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/directshownetcf/